# Complete graph $K_{19}$ in 3-space with all distances at powers of $d$

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, graph-theory, combinatorial-geometry, extremal-combinatorics

For 2D, I asked the question [Points with power distances](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1828794/points-with-power-distances).  For 3D, I asked about [Points at Integer Distances in 3-space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285620/points-at-integer-distances-in-3-space). Combining these, I was able to construct $K_{19}$ so that all distance between points are powers of $d=1.15096...$ from $d^6 -d^2-1=0$, the same as in [Zak's triangle](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/851275). For smaller cliques, see [Powered Clique Polyhedra](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PoweredCliquePolyhedra/).

[image: powerful K19]

Here's the grid of power distances between points.  For example, the 16-17 distance is $d^0$. Values are 0 to 17 sans 1 and 16.

[image: powerful K19 grid]

Points 1-3 can be placed at the following, with the root value about 4.54932.
{{d^6 /2, Root[-19+72 #1^2 -1328 #1^4 +64 #1^6 &,2], 0}, {0,0,0}, {d^6,0,0}}

That leads to the first question -- is there a natural way of representing this pyramid, so that all coordinates are expressed in terms of $d$, or so that it is placed symmetrically on the $(x,y,z)$ axis?  Is it possible to get larger cliques?

Are there any other $d$ values that can even get close to power-distance clique this large?

[image: power K19 2]

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following set of 19 triples:

```
{{{-19, 0, 19}, {19, 76, 57}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{-76, -57, 57}, {0, 19, 57}, {0, 0, 0}}, 
 {{0, -19, 0}, {76, 133, 76}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{76, 76,0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, 
 {{76, 95, 76}, {76, 133, 76}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{-38, 0, 19}, {38, 0, 19}, {0, 0, 0}}, 
 {{95, 19, -57}, {-19, 57, -19}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, -19, 19}, {0, 19, 57}, {0, 0, 0}}, 
 {{-38, 0, 19}, {42, 68, 43}, {-4, 8, 52}}, {{19, 38, -38}, {17, 42, 26}, {40, -4, 12}}, 
 {{19, 38, -38}, {9, -18, 54}, {-28, 56, -16}}, {{0, -19, 19}, {36, 99, 45}, {40, -4, 12}}, 
 {{-152, -171, -76}, {76, 133, 76}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{76, 95, -76}, {76, 133, 76}, {0, 0, 0}}, 
 {{76, -57, 0}, {76, 133, 76}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{76, 76, 0}, {16, 44, 20}, {60, 108, 56}}, 
 {{95, 19, -57}, {49, 73, 9}, {8, 60, 48}}, {{-76, -57, 57}, {36, 99, 45}, {40, -4, 12}}, 
 {{-19, 0, 19}, {47, 96, 73}, {-28, 56, -16}}}/76
```

Use each triple in $sign(k) \sqrt{|k|}$ where $k=a p^0 +b p^1 + c p^2$ and $p$ is the [plastic constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlasticConstant.html), $p^3-p-1=0$ and $p=1.32472...$.  All the distances between points are powers of $\sqrt{p}$.

Here's a 2D figure for [Points at power distances](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1828794/points-with-power-distances). Divide the triples $(a,b,c)$ in each point by 4 first before plugging into $sign(k) \sqrt{|k|}$ where $k=a p^0 +b p^1 + c p^2$. The larger numbers give the distance $\sqrt{p^n}$ between the points.

[image: plastic pentagon]